# How do I read a file into a variable with an unknown number of quotes in Bash

Tags: bash, git-bash

I try to read a file into a variable with `git-bash`. I am using something like this:

```sh
readFile() {
    local file="${1}"
    local resultVar="${2}"
    eval $resultVar="'$(cat ${file})'"
}
```

Similar to what is suggested here [Link](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions).

This works fine in most cases. But it can cause issues depending on the number of quotes in the files. For example:

#### Example 1 ❌

`test1.txt`:

```
text "quoted"
```

`code`:

```sh
$ echo "text \"quoted\"" > test1.txt &&
> readFile "./test1.txt" test1 &&
> printf "test1: %s\n" "${test1}"
test1: text "quoted"
```

**ERROR**: Cuts of the trailing `\n` at the end.

#### Example 2 ❌

`test2.txt`:

```
text "one quote
```

`code`:

```sh
$ echo "text \"one quote" > test2.txt &&
> readFile "./test2.txt" test2 &&
> printf "test2: %s\n" "${test2}"
test2: text "one quote
```

**ERROR**: Cuts of the trailing `\n` at the end.

#### Example 3 ❌

`test3.txt`:

```
text 'quoted'
```

`code`:

```sh
$ echo "text 'quoted'" > test3.txt &&
> readFile "./test3.txt" test3 &&
> printf "test3: %s\n" "${test3}"
test3: text quoted
```

**ERROR**: These `single-quotes` have been removed!

#### Example 4 ❌

`test4.txt`:

```
text 'one quote
```

`code`:

```sh
$ echo "text 'one quote" > test4.txt &&
> readFile "./test4.txt" test4 &&
> printf "test4: %s\n" "${test4}"
bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

**ERROR**: This gets even worse...

#### Example 5 ❌

`test5.txt`:

```
text 'quoted"
```

`code`:

```sh
$ echo "text \'quoted\"" > test5.txt &&
> readFile "./test5.txt" test5 &&
> printf "test5: %s\n" "${test5}"
bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

**ERROR**: Similar to the above.

---

**So, how can I robustly read a file from within a function into a variable without knowing if, how many and what type of quotes it contains?**

Maybe there are other characters that could also break my code, but I didn't check for that. It would be nice if a solution would also take care of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this achieve what you wanted ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
readFile() {
    IFS= read -rd '' "$1" < "$2"
}   

readFile var data-file

# Checking result
printf %s "$var" | xxd
```

Comment: It does indeed! The `readarray` version of KamilCuk does also work, but I accepted this one because it's a little faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use eval.

In `bash`, you can `$(<file)` instead of `$(cat file)`. It's just a bit faster.

You can use a namereference:

```
readFile() {
    declare -n resultVar=$2
    resultVar="$(<"$1")"
}
```

If there are no zero bytes, you could use readarray/mapfile. Note - it will preserve the trailing newline, in opposed to `$(...)` that removes trailing newlines:

```
readFile() {
    readarray -d '' -t "$2" < "$1"
}
```

If you really want to use `eval`, then use `declare`:

```
readFile() {
    declare -g "$2=$(< "$1")"
}
```

If you really really want to use `eval`, always pass a properly escaped string to it, ie. always after `printf "%q"`:

```
readFile() {
    eval "$(printf "%q" "$2")=$(printf "%q" "$(< "$1")")"
}
```

Comment: A much better solution than `eval` is `printf -v "$2" "%q" "$(<  "$1")"` or probably just `printf -v "$2" "%s" "$1"` if that's what you want.

Comment: @tripleee I think you meant `printf -v "$2" "%s" "$(<"$1")"` in your 2nd example. But it also cuts off the `\n` at the end of the file. `\n`s before that are handled correctly. Can this be modified to work? (I adjusted the question as I found out that my first 2 examples were also cutting of the trailing `\n`)

Comment: If you want to preserve the file as-is, I would suggest to encode file content in hex with ex. `xxd`. `$(...)` removes trailing newlines, and bash is not capable of storing zero bytes. Ie. bash is not suited to handle binary data, it's a shell, best used for handling user readable nice looking strings.

Comment: Command substitutions by definition remove any trailing newlines from the captured value. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: @KamilCuk Can you give an example?

Comment: @tripleee Apparently, that's how it is. But not the way I want it ;)

Comment: `fileconent=$(xxd -p file)` and then `xxd -r -p <<<"$filecontent" | cat # some parsing`. But that sounds like a file copy with extra steps.

Comment: @KamilCuk But doesn't this come down to the same issue? If I get the hexdump via `filecontentHex=$(xxd -p "$1")` then I cannot process it directly and have to create the readible version first. For example with: `printf "%s" "${filecontentHex}" | xxd -r -p`. This is also printing the trailing `\n` btw. But when I want to put it into a variable I would have to use command substitution `$(...)` again, which then removes the trailing `\n` again.

Comment: Why would you ever need (trailing) newlines in variables? `want to put it into a variable I would have to use command substitution $(...) again` Yes, so what's the point? In most contexts newlines are badly handled by the shell. `<<<` add a newline, `echo` adds a newline, `$(...)` ignores trailing newlines. Either you deal with binary data - in which case you use `xxd` and do not ever use bash to do anything with it (or parse it as hex) - or you deal with human readable stings - in which case you use shell.

Comment: `read file into variable`, `change variable`, `save new file base on variable` for example without loosing the trailing `\n`.

Comment: Don't. Read file into a stream - in a stream modify the content (`sed`, `awk` most unix tools work on _streams_, not on state) - save to file. One of the most common unix tools - `sed` is literally named after Stream EDitor. How do you want to change the file content? Streams is the most natural way of working in shells. You are adding an extra step "variable" - it's not needed. Modify the file, not the variable.